# html form option value as part of $_POST or $_GET multidimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, forms

I'm trying to setup a simple dropdown menu that echoes a value of an array corresponding to the option value submitted via $_GET.

I don't understand how to use one if construct using variables in a multidimensional array. I could easy type up as many if constructs as I needed, but there has to be a way to do this via $_GET['selectname'][$n]

What am I doing wrong?

```
$animal = array("cat", "dog", "fish", "bear");    

//generates dropdown menu of animals with option value of 1-4
echo "<form method=\"GET\"><select name=\"animaltype\">";
for($n = 0; $n < 4; $n++)
{
    echo "<option value=\"$n\">$animal[$n]</option>";
}
echo "</select><input type=\"submit\"></form>";

//use variables in multidimensional array to use one if construct instead of many
if(isset($_GET['animaltype'][$n]))
{
    echo $animal[$n];
}
```

Comment: just like jeroen said, since you dont have a `multitple="multiple"` attribute, `$_GET['animaltype']` will contain a string which you selected on the dropdown form, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show what animal was select, you can do:

```
if(isset($_GET['animaltype']))
{
    echo $animal[$_GET['animaltype']];
}
```

`$_GET['animaltype']` is not an array, it is a string that contains the value of the selected option.